# Loading VDB files in Blender using command line

Tags: cycles-render-engine, command-line

My blender scene has a Vdb volume object, and I am rendering it in cycles. I wish to perform the rendering using command line (in hpc). I am looking for a command to specify vdb files in command line arguments. Is it possible?
Regards,
Nitesh